# 301 redirect - apache or php for my case?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, header, http-status-code-301

I have a blog www.SITE_NAME.com which is hosted in blogger.com, Its almost 4 year old and have better search engine ranking. Most of the traffic came through Google. Now i am redesigning my site in drupal.

So i want to redirect all older links with a 301 to new pages , Since i have nearly 700 pages , i want some logic to apply (and some case i want to redirect manually) . Which is better, using Apache or php? Or any other suggestion?

Note :  since my old site is in blogger.com, its path is something like this `www.SITE_NAME.com/2007/08/music.html` and my new path will be like `www.SITE_NAME.com/DYNAMIC_PATH`

Comment: How easy is it to rewrite the URL to the new `DYNAMIC_PATH`? Is it a simple regex, or something better written out in PHP code?

Comment: Does blogger support custom php code? If not, you will be forced to make use of apache via an.htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These scripts should be placed in the .htaccess file.

```
//*301 Redirect: xyz-site.com to www.xyz-site.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xyz-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

//*301 Redirect: www.xyz-site.com to xyz-site.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xyz-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xyz-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

//*301 Redirect: Redirecting Individual pages

Redirect 301 /previous-page.html http://www.xyz-site.com/new-page.html
```

Or you can use

Redirect with PHP

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.xyz-site.com" );
exit(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if we are talking about performance, - then defiantly .htaccess/apache will be better/faster. if you wanna implement some logic on redirect, when probably it will be easier to do with php, using headers.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the 301. It lets search engines know that the site is moved permanently and should transfer any "link weighting" from the old URL to the new one. Check out this info from [Google Webmasters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105)

And this about [redirecting tons of links](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/mhaJ1g3VqCg)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't post comments yet. If the domain is the same, you should "bild" same site structure (same permalinks) and I guess use something like this:

http://drupal.org/project/blogger_importer

Then you should not use any redirects at all.

Comment: Thanks, Actually i dont want any contents from old blog, but just have to tell xxx.html moved to NEW.html

Comment: I have a "similar case" (old useles CMS and a lot of php pages), but I use Codeigniter instead of Drupal. I usually use .htaccess Redirect and RedirectMatch but also I have a routes.php. I don't know if Drupal have something like that: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html